# Docker - how do i restart nginx to apply custom config?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to configure a LEMP dev environment with docker and am having trouble with `nginx` because I can't seem to restart `nginx` once it has it's new configuration.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/config/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
  php:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I have a custom `nginx` config that replaces `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, and in a normal Ubuntu environment, I would run `service nginx restart` to pull in the new config.

However, if I try to do that this Docker environment, the `nginx` container `exits with code 1`.

```
docker-compose exec nginx sh
service nginx restart

-exit with code 1-
```

How would I be able use `nginx` with a custom `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically you can [reload](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nginx) nginx configuration by invoking this command:

```
docker exec <nginx-container-name-or-id> nginx -s reload
```

Answer (score 5):

To reload nginx with docker-compose specifically (rather than restart the whole container, causing downtime):

```
docker-compose exec nginx nginx -s reload
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers should be running a single application in the foreground. When that process it launches as pid 1 inside the container exits, so does the container (similar to how killing pid 1 on a linux server will shutdown that machine). This process isn't managed by the OS service command.

The normal way to reload a configuration in a container is to restart the container. Since you're using `docker-compose`, that would be `docker-compose restart nginx`. Note that if this config was part of your image, you would need to rebuild and redeploy a new container, but since you're using a volume, that isn't necessary.

Comment: I did try using `docker-compose restart nginx` and that restarted the container, but my intended config was not being pulled in.  That may be because the config path in this case is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` instead of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.  However, when mounting the volume: `- ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d`, the nginx container exits immediately after starting.  Regardless, you have answered my original question.  If you have any advice on how to find out why a container exited immediately, I'd love to hear it.